# How to change column type from list to str pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Data Frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'word':[['one', 'two', 'four'],
                                    ['five', 'six', 'nine'], 
                                    ['eight', 'eleven', 'ten']]})

    id  word
0   1   [one, two, four]
1   2   [five, six, nine]
2   3   [eight, eleven, ten]
```

The dtype of my values stored in "word" column is `list`. I want that values to become `str` instead.
I've tried this:

```
df2 =  df[df.word.map(lambda y: " ".join(y))]
```

But it raised me an error:

```
KeyError: "['one two four' 'five six nine' 'eight eleven ten'] not in index"
```

Please, advise me something to solve my problem.

Comment: `df.word.str.join(',')` or `df.word.apply(','.join)` or `map(','.join, df.word)`?

Comment: Comma or space. Doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close. You're trying to select from the dataframe. Just remove an extra `df` and set of brackets and you're there! :

```
df2 =  df.word.map(lambda y: " ".join(y))
```

Comment: also, `df.word.map(','.join)`

Comment: Thanks)) Such a mistake of mine

Answer (score 2):

```
df['word_str'] = df.word.str.join(',')
```

creates a new column with the words joined by comma

```
df['word'] = df.word.str.join(',')
```

will overwrite the existing column

Answer (score 1):

You are getting key error because you are trying to select the data from df after joining the list values. So instead use `copy` for not altering existing dataframe and `assign` to change the word column

```
df2 = df.copy().assign(word = df.word.map(lambda y: " ".join(y)))
```

Or

```
df2 = df.copy().assign(word = df.word.str.join(" "))

df2
```

```
  id              word
0   1      one two four
1   2     five six nine
2   3  eight eleven ten
```

```
df2['word'][0]
'one two four'
```